# Is there a function in R to create simulated categorical variables from logistic regression results?

Tags: r, simulation, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I can create continuous and binary variables from a set of logistic regression results. However, I am struggling to create categorical variables from a set of logistic regression results.

For example, based on the Titanic dataset, that is available in base R, I can create simulated variables for Adults and Males. However, I am unable to simulate variables for the categorical variable “Class” which has 4 levels (First, Second, Third and Crew). The binary response variable is Survived.

The R code is below.

Any advice on how to simulate a variable for “Class” would be much appreciated.

Many thanks for your time,

Paul

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(sjPlot)
# Step 1 - Load the dataset
data(Titanic)
# Step 2 - Transform the Titanic dataset
mydata \<- reshape2::melt(Titanic) %\>%
uncount(value) %\>%
as_tibble
mydata
# Step 3 - Create the dummy variables
mydata$Crew \<- ifelse(mydata$Class == "Crew", 1, 0)
mydata$First \<- ifelse(mydata$Class == "1st", 1, 0)
mydata$Second \<- ifelse(mydata$Class == "2nd", 1, 0)
mydata$Third \<- ifelse(mydata$Class == "3rd", 1, 0)
mydata$Male \<- ifelse(mydata$Sex == "Male", 1, 0)
mydata$Female \<- ifelse(mydata$Sex == "Female", 1, 0)
mydata$Child \<- ifelse(mydata$Age == "Child", 1, 0)
mydata$Adult \<- ifelse(mydata$Age == "Adult", 1, 0)
#Step 4 - Fit the logistic regression model
glm.1 \<- glm(Survived \~ Second + Third + Crew + Adult + Male, family = binomial("logit"), data = mydata )
#Step 5 – View the model summary
summary(glm.1)
# Step 6 - Create the simulated data
set.seed(016752277)
Male \<- sample(c(0,1), size = 2000, replace = TRUE)
Adult \<- sample(c(0,1), size = 2000, replace = TRUE)
xb \<- 3.1054 + -2.4201*Male + -1.0615*Adult
p \<- 1/(1 + exp(-xb))
Survived \<- rbinom(n = 2000, size = 1, prob = p)
# Step 7 - Fit the logistic regression model based on the simulated data
glm.1simulated \<- glm(Survived \~ Male + Adult, family = "binomial")
# Step 8 - View the model summary based on the simulated data
summary(glm.1simulated)
# Step 9 – View both models side by side
tab_model(glm.1, glm.1simulated)
```

Comment: Two comments:  1. Something went wrong when you copied your code, and there are lots of things like `\<-` in it; these are syntax errors, so your code won't run.  2.  It's not clear what you want to do.  What properties do you want the simulated variable to have, other than being a factor with those 4 levels?

Comment: You might be looking for multinomial logistic regression or proportional odds logistic regression https://peopleanalytics-regression-book.org/multinomial-logistic-regression-for-nominal-category-outcomes.html (incl. R examples).  However, please consider migrating mainly statistical issues to the Stats platform: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are probably making this a bit harder than it needs to be. There is no need to create all those dummy variables - your initial model is as simple as

```r
data(Titanic)

mydata <- tidyr::uncount(as.data.frame(Titanic), Freq)

glm.1 <- glm(Survived ~ ., mydata, family = binomial)

summary(glm.1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = Survived ~ ., family = binomial, data = mydata)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)   0.6853     0.2730   2.510   0.0121 *  
#> Class2nd     -1.0181     0.1960  -5.194 2.05e-07 ***
#> Class3rd     -1.7778     0.1716 -10.362  < 2e-16 ***
#> ClassCrew    -0.8577     0.1573  -5.451 5.00e-08 ***
#> SexFemale     2.4201     0.1404  17.236  < 2e-16 ***
#> AgeAdult     -1.0615     0.2440  -4.350 1.36e-05 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 2769.5  on 2200  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 2210.1  on 2195  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 2222.1
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

For the predictor variables of your simulated data, simply sample the unique levels of the factors in your original data frame

```r
set.seed(016752277)

new_data <- data.frame(Class = sample(unique(mydata$Class), 2000, TRUE),
                       Sex   = sample(unique(mydata$Sex), 2000, TRUE),
                       Age   = sample(unique(mydata$Age), 2000, TRUE))
```

To get the probabilities implied by the factor levels, you can use `predict` instead of manually calculating the log odds and converting them to probabilities:

```
probs    <- predict(glm.1, newdata = new_data, type = "response")
```

If for some reason you only have the model summary (and not the model itself), then you can get the log odds of each observation by simple arithmetic and using `plogis` to convert them to probabilities. The following therefore gives the same result as `predict` (apart from rounding errors due to only using three decimal places):

```r
probs <- with(new_data, plogis( 0.6853 + 
                               -1.0181 * (Class == "2nd")    +
                               -1.7778 * (Class == "3rd")    +
                               -0.8577 * (Class == "Crew")   +
                                2.4201 * (Sex   == "Female") + 
                               -1.0615 * (Age   == "Adult")))
```

Now your simulation is just:

```r
new_data$Survived <- rbinom(n = 2000, size = 1, prob = probs)
```

And your simulated model is:

```r
glm.1simulated <- glm(Survived ~ ., new_data, family = binomial)

summary(glm.1simulated)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = Survived ~ ., family = binomial, data = new_data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)   0.4911     0.1234   3.980 6.90e-05 ***
#> Class2nd     -0.9145     0.1561  -5.857 4.72e-09 ***
#> Class3rd     -1.7217     0.1605 -10.727  < 2e-16 ***
#> ClassCrew    -0.8648     0.1548  -5.588 2.30e-08 ***
#> SexFemale     2.4114     0.1176  20.505  < 2e-16 ***
#> AgeAdult     -0.9605     0.1115  -8.614  < 2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 2747.9  on 1999  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 2080.5  on 1994  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 2092.5
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

And this compares well to the original model:

```r
sjPlot::tab_model(glm.1, glm.1simulated)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, or at least the one in the title:  "create simulated categorical variables from logistic regression results".  I'm not sure what that means, and the OP hasn't clarified it, so I'm going to vote to close.

Comment: @user2554330 the OP explicitly says that they don't know how to simulate the four categorical levels of the `Class` variable, and both the code and the context makes it quite clear that they mean they don't know how to _sample_ the four levels of the `Class` variable to allow them to simulate the `Survived` variable. I think that if I took a stubbornly literal  reading of the question I would share your opinion here, but in general I try to understand what the OP is _really_ asking. Perhaps this is the wrong approach. It's good to hear a different opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your time in looking at the question. I am sorry if it is a bit clumsy in the way it is written.

To get the implied probabilities by factor levels using this piece of code:

probs    <- predict(glm.1, newdata = new_data, type = "response")

 

Is there a way to get the factor levels from the coefficients in the results themselves. Eg:

(Intercept -  0.6853) + (Class2nd * -1.0181) + (Class3rd * -1.7778) + (ClassCrew * -0.8577) + (SexFemale  * 2.4201) + (AgeAdult * -1.0615)

 

There will be circumstances, when only the model output is available.

Comment: Allan,

This is a very elegant solution to my question.

Many thanks for your time. You have been very generous with your knowledge.

Best wishes,

Paul